# Combining two tables with multiple common columns into one in SQL

Tags: sql-server, create-table

I am trying to create a table in SQL server which has the same output as the following:

```
Select *  
FROM Table1  
LEFT JOIN Table2  
ON  
    Table1.Key1 = Table2.Key1 
AND Table1.Key2 = Table2.Key2
```

The result of the above query is exactly what I need, but as a new table.

The problem is, there are multiple columns that are common between the two tables. I have executed the following code:

```
Select *  
INTO NewTable  
FROM Table1  
LEFT JOIN Table2  
ON    
    Table1.Key1 = Table2.Key1 
AND Table1.Key2 = Table2.Key2
```

The following error appears:

> Msg 2705, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 
>   Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'Key1' in table 'NewTable' is specified more than once.

Could someone please help? I would highly appreciate it after a long day of searching the internet without any solution.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Error message clearly says some columns name are duplicate, you have to mentioned all column name explicitly

Comment: The * is your problem.

Comment: The problem is that there are hundreds of columns in both tables, and many are common. I would like to know if there is a way to automatically ignore the same columns as it is in the results of the first code.

Comment: Are you really trying to create a new *table*, or are you just trying to get query output between the two tables?

Comment: I have already got a query output between the two tables with the first code. Now I need to create a new table for inserting new operations into the columns which require data from both tables.

Comment: @KeithL How would you recommend changing that to a correct code?

Comment: I provided you a solution below to spell out your column names with minimal effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you identify what records you need to get a unique list.

```
select ',' + Column_Name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c2
where column_Name not in (
                        select COLUMN_NAME
                        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                        where TABLE_NAME = 'table1')
and table_Name = 'Table2'
```

So you can safely say:

```
Select table1.*
    <<Paste in your results from above here>>  
INTO NewTable  
FROM Table1  
LEFT JOIN Table2  
ON    
    Table1.Key1 = Table2.Key1 
AND Table1.Key2 = Table2.Key2
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I needed and it did the job perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

When you write select into table query then it dynamically create the table and at the time of creating a table the name of column should be unique.

In your case when you join then name of column can be in both table.

So replace * and write it as shown below

```
Select Column1, Column2, ... etc  
INTO NewTable  
FROM Table1  
LEFT JOIN Table2  
ON    
    Table1.Key1 = Table2.Key1 
AND Table1.Key2 = Table2.Key2
```

Comment: The problem is that there are hundreds of columns in both tables, and many are common. I would like to know if there is a way to automatically ignore the same columns as it is in the results of the first code.

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest option would be to change your select-into statement into something like this, where you give unique names to the fields with the same name:

```
Select Table1.Key1 as [Key1a], Table2.Key1 as [Key1b], etc.
INTO NewTable  
FROM Table1  
LEFT JOIN Table2  
ON    
    Table1.Key1 = Table2.Key1 
AND Table1.Key2 = Table2.Key2
```

If you are using SSMS, you could highlight your query, right-click on it and select "Design in Query Editor" and it will show you the select statement as "select [all of the fields]" rather than "select *", which will probably be useful to you.